# Объясните порядок действий. Как выполняется преобразования когда складываем массивы?

Tags: javascript

```
null + {0:1}[0] + [,[1],][1][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего нужно определиться с тем, что именно складывается:

1. null
2. `{0:1}[0]` -> `1` // доступ к полю объекта
3. `[,[1],][1][0]` -> `[1][0]` -> `1`

В итоге получаем

```
null + 1 + 1
```

Далее обращаемся к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation), и получаем следующее

```
ToNumber(null) + ToNumber(1) + ToNumber(1)
```

В той же [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber) видим, что `ToNumber(null) == +0`

В итоге получаем

```
+0 + 1 + 1
```

Что равно: 2

---

Стоит также обратить внимание на то, что в данном случае складываются не массивы, а конкретное значение свойства объекта, и конкретный элемент массива.

Comment: Почему в третьем действии из массива [,[1],][1][0] получается [1][0]?

Comment: `[,[1],][1][0] === ([,[1],][1])[0] === ([1])[0] === [1][0] === 1`

Comment: вторая и треться пара квадратны скобочек ([1][0]) не являются массивами, это последовательное применение оператора получения значения по индексу (который записывается в виде кведратных скобочек с индексом внутри).

Comment: Массивом в третьем примере является только `[,[1],]` который эквивалентен массиву из 2х элементов `[ <empty_slot>, [1] ]`, где `<empty_slot>` - неинициализированное поле.